# Multiple "is" in Python

Tags: python

I have a list with a few hundred of objects, and I want to check, if a newcomer object is already added to my list (not an equal object, but exactly this exact instance).

I have a dumb realization like this:

```
def is_one_of(test_object, all_objects):
    for elm in all_objects:
        if test_object is elm:
            return True
    return False
```

Cannot it be more beautiful?

Answer (score 4):

use `any`:

```
if any(x is test_object for x in all_objects):
```

The [example in the python reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) looks remarkably similar to your code already :)

Comment: Cannot I make it faster, than linear search? Maybe, there is some way to force Python `set` to use `id(...)` as hash function?

Comment: @Felix -- No way to make it faster for `all_objects` as an arbitrary container.  Of course, if `all_objects` was a `dict` or a `set` ... then yes with an appropriately defined `__hash__` ...

Comment: My solution was bad and this is actually the best one, so +1

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
def is_one_of(test_object, all_objects):
    return any(test_object is elm for elm in all_objects)
```

It'll stop iterating over the generator expression as soon as a `True` result is found.

Comment: FGITW'd you by 16s ;-).

Comment: 2s -- 16s.  Might as well be 3 hours ;-)

Comment: True -- But it doesn't matter how fast your gun is if you _miss_.  Anwyay, I'm just excited because I don't get the change to be FGITW very much these days -- Especially not against the great ninja Martijn Pieters!

Comment: Gotta watch out for those bunnies ... They definitely dull the reflexes.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, I made it by putting id(element) to a set:

```
def _unit_list(self):
    """
    Returns all units in the order they should be initialized.
    (Performs search by width from start_point).
    """
    unit_id_set = set()
    unit_list = []
    unit_id_set.add(self.start_point)
    unit_list.append(self.start_point)
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(unit_list):
        cur_unit = unit_list[pos]
        for child in cur_unit.links_to:
            if not (id(child) in unit_id_set):
                unit_list.append(child)
                unit_id_set.add(id(child))
        pos += 1
    return unit_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if any(test_object is x for x in all_objects): ...
```

if you need to do this test often however may be you can keep a set of all object `id`s instead

```
all_ids = set(map(id, all_objects))
```

then you can check faster with

```
if id(test_object) in all_ids: ...
```

Another common solution that may apply is to store in the object itself in a specific field if it has been already processed:

```
# add the object to the list
all_objects.append(x)
x.added = True

...

# Check if already added
if test_object.added: ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for the `in` operator. The equivalent function would be:

```
def is_one_of(test_object, all_objects):
    return test_object in all_objects
```

(but you really wouldn't want to write that as a function).

Edit: I'm wrong. According to the [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) page:

> For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.

That would work *if* your class doesn't define `__eq__`, but that's more fragile than I'd want to rely on. For example:

```
class ObjWithEq(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

a = ObjWithEq(1)
b = ObjWithEq(1)

assert a == b
assert a in [b]


class ObjWithoutEq(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

a = ObjWithoutEq(1)
b = ObjWithoutEq(1)

assert a != b
assert a not in [b]
```

Comment: No, because `in` uses *equality* tests, not identity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's *probably* true, in that it's correct if equality is defined. The default behavior for classes without `__eq__` is actually what OP is asking for, but I wouldn't trust it. If a later maintainer decides comparison is a good thing and defines it, then code will break. Still, it *does* work by default.

Comment: That's because the *default object.__eq__` implementation is to return True only when the objects are identical. But it still uses `.__eq__`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser -- But OP already specified "Not an _equal object_, but exactly this instance".  FWIW though, I always thought it was a bit of a shame that for various list methods (`.remove`, `.index`, ...) the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) uses the word "is" when they really mean "equals"...